# Verify if the user exists using Bcrypt and Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bcrypt

I'm developing a login with sping and currently I have my password encrypted with Bcrypt.
I have a user on my h2 database and to verify if the user credentials are correct and don't know what is advised.Should decrypt both passwords and compare them (I think that not the correct way to do it of course) or should I use another mechanism to verify if the user's credetials are right?

Answer (score 2):

Your password is not encrypted with BCrypt, because BCrypt is not an encryption algorithm. It's a *one-way hashing* algorithm.

Being one way, as every cryptographic hash function, you can't "decrypt" the hashed password. All you can do is hash the submitted password and verify that the new hash matches the stored one.

How to do that is described, with example code and everything, in [the javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html) of the BCrypt class provided by Spring.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it really helped me!

Comment: But when I authenticate the user should I leave his password with no hashing when comparing the hash that's on the database?

Comment: You should do as the javadoc says: `if (BCrypt.checkpw(candidate_password, stored_hash))`. The checkpw method will salt and hash the candidate password (i.e. the password that the user submitted to log in), and compare the result with the stored hash. If they match, it returns true. If not, it returns false. The javadoc says: *Check that a plaintext password matches a previously hashed one*. What is unclear?

Comment: I understood that and I was doing that from the beginning, my doubt is that the password would be unprotected when I compare it to the hash that I have on the database.My point is, is secure to have the password unprotected to compare it to the hash?

Comment: unprotected from what? A password is usually submitted over https. https encrypts everything that goes on the wire.

Comment: Oh ok that was my doubt, sorry to bother you and thanks for all the explanation!